# Azure SDK 1.5 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I had Azure SDK 1.4 installed on my machine (win7-64) that was used in VS2010-SP1.
now I started working on a project that is using Azure SDK 1.5, while trying to upgrade, the SDK, via with WPI3.0.
The installation failed, with the error: "Windows Azure SDK this product did not install sueccessfully".

So, I have decided to try to install it manually from the folder ...\50F77816F4EAEA75902EAE4F5C980656052EAB88\WindowsAzureSDK-x64.exe. before that, I have removed the Azure SDK 1.4 + restart) which resulted an error: "The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 2738." ("regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll" didn't help as well...)

Any ideas?

WPI error log:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767054
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9767054 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:41:25 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=b28ba68909cb9f4fb2743cebb287bbb8&HASH=89a6&LV=20119&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:24 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Sep 2011 00:14:47 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "fb334c4e2a77cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 438616531000000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:26 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\542864071.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Mon, 19 Sep 2011 18:48:23 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "dc09db5fc76cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 279981030800000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:26 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1338951197.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Sep 2011 00:24:00 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "256f3f9bbd6dcc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 279183230500000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:27 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\664384761.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/toolsproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Sep 2011 06:06:39 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2b55cd77a472cc1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 79171731300000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:27 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1956869252.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/3.0/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Apr 2011 17:49:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2c1614f082f4cb1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
VTag: 791755030500000000
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:27 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\903079739.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 6, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:41:29 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=f8eb0e8292bad14cbadbe1be35bf82be&HASH=820e&LV=20119&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 21 Sep 2011 11:42:29 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - September 2011 (WindowsAzureToolsVS2010) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 (AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Removing product Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 (AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD) from cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 (AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Removing product Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - September 2011 (WindowsAzureToolsVS2010) from cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Removing product Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 (AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD) from cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 (AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - September 2011 (WindowsAzureToolsVS2010) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework4' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WindowsImagingComponent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureSDK' for product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'ASPNET' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'StaticContent' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASProcessModel' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETExtensibility' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'RequestFiltering' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASNetFxEnvironment' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'ISAPIExtensions' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'ISAPIFilters' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'DefaultDocument' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'CGI' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'UrlRewrite2' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'FastCGIUpdate' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'NETFramework35' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'PowerShell' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Dependent product PowerShellMsu does not apply for current OS / configuration. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'IISManagementConsole' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'WASConfigurationAPI' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'DirectoryBrowse' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPErrors' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPRedirection' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'HTTPLogging' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'LoggingTools' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'Tracing' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'RequestMonitor' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010ToolsOnly' for product 'WindowsAzureToolsVS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'VS2010SP1Core' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'VS2010SP1Prerequisite' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product 'MVC3' is installed. Not adding
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC3Installer' for product 'MVC3'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No SQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : No MySQL to configure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/9/5/F95A2093-134F-4182-8C0E-8678699202F4/WindowsAzureAppFabricSDK-x64.msi' to: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9EF0.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9EF0.tmp' to: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD\30D476EC3B25D7A180805C3DD4F2986BAD882879\WindowsAzureAppFabricSDK-x641.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureSDK\50f77816f4eaea75902eae4f5c980656052eab88\WindowsAzureSDK-x64.exe instead of downloading from http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/C/84C12C90-0831-485B-A181-A11A56389826/WindowsAzureSDK-x64.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\AzureAppFabricSDKV1PROD\30D476EC3B25D7A180805C3DD4F2986BAD882879\WindowsAzureAppFabricSDK-x641.msi', commandline: 'ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureToolsVS2010ToolsOnly\08958b0b72b3b9c71836a8ac6e14ea4cf484d9db\VSCloudService.VS100.en-us.msi instead of downloading from http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/C/84C12C90-0831-485B-A181-A11A56389826/VSCloudService.VS100.en-us.msi
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC3Installer\7a15ca7a49ac8a9edfe71ac0873a8aa38338c029\AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe instead of downloading from http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/1/F31EF055-3C46-4E35-AB7B-3261A303A3B6/AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5' is 0
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Windows Azure AppFabric SDK V1.5 installation log: C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2011-09-21T14.43.00\WindowsAzureAppFabricSDK-x641.txt
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure SDK'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsAzureSDK\50f77816f4eaea75902eae4f5c980656052eab88\WindowsAzureSDK-x64.exe /quiet /norestart'. Process Id: 3112
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure SDK' is 1603
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure SDK' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure SDK done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 3
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 v1.5'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 v1.5 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 4
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - September 2011'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - September 2011 had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 5
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC3Installer\7a15ca7a49ac8a9edfe71ac0873a8aa38338c029\AspNetMVC3ToolsUpdateSetup.exe /q /log C:\Users\XXXUser\AppData\Local\Temp\mvc3_install.htm'. Process Id: 3596
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer' is 0
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer' is Success
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update Installer done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/95579e93-0a46-4627-857b-f1c354526885

this helped: http://blogs.technet.com/b/fixit4me/archive/2009/03/31/error-code-2738-when-running-a-microsoft-fix-it-solution.aspx

Thank you all